# Create a key:value pair in the first loop and append more values in subsequent loops

Tags: python

How can I create a key:value pair in a first loop and then just append values in subsequent loops?
For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [8,9,10]
c = [4,6,5]

myList= [a,b,c]
positions= ['first_position', 'second_position', 'third_position']
```

I would like to create a dictionary which records the position values for each letter so:

```
mydict = {'first_position':[1,8,4], 'second_position':[2,9,6], 'third_position':[3,10,5]}
```

Imagine that instead of 3 letters with 3 values each, I had millions. How could I loop through each letter and:

1. In the first loop create the key:value pair 'first_position':[1]
2. In subsequent loops append values to the corresponding key: 'first_position':[1,8,4]

Thanks!

Comment: Which part are you struggling with, specifically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
mydict = {}
for i in range(len(positions)):
    mydict[positions[i]] = [each[i] for each in myList]
```

Output:

```
{'first_position': [1, 8, 4],
 'second_position': [2, 9, 6],
 'third_position': [3, 10, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

dictionary.get('key') will return None if the key doesn't exist. So, you can check if the value is None and then append it if it isn't.

```
dict = {}
for list in myList: 
  for position, val in enumerate(list):
    this_position = positions[position]
    if dict.get(this_position) is not None:
      dict[this_position].append(val)
    else:
      dict[this_position] = [val]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `zip` function will iterate the i'th values of `positions`, `a`, `b` and `c` in order. So,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [8,9,10]
c = [4,6,5]

positions= ['first_position', 'second_position', 'third_position']
sources = [positions, a, b, c]

mydict = {vals[0]:vals[1:] for vals in zip(*sources)}
print(mydict)
```

This created tuples which is usually fine if the lists are read only. Otherwise do

```
mydict = {vals[0]:list(vals[1:]) for vals in zip(*sources)}
```